# Sencha Touch Store is not loading

Tags: json, sencha-touch-2

I have a Store that need to load DataView,
I used Dummy Data until today and it work just fine,
I want to use a web page to load the data.
my store code is:

```
Ext.define("myApp.store.myStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    alias: "widget.myStore",   
    model: "myApp.model.myModel",
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        type: 'ajax',
        method: 'post',
        url: 'URL'
        }),     
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader(
            {
                type:'json',
                rootProperty:'Results'
            }),    

autoLoad: true,
config: {
    sorters: [{ property: 'MyProp', direction: 'ASC'}],
    grouper: {
        sortProperty: "MyOtherProp",
        direction: "ASC",
        groupFn: function (record) {
            if (record && record.data.MyOtherProp) {
                return record.data.MyProp;
            } else {
                return '';
            }


           }
        }

    }
});
```

In Firebug I can see that the result is 0 items (and the url have 2 items..)
What am I doing Wrong?? 
Thanks!

Comment: the Error in the Debug is "Web Console(10369): Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getTotal' at file:///android_asset/www/st2/sencha-touch-all-debug.js:30885
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to set the URL to a specific location.

Comment: Hmmm, the Uncaught TypeError may be a caused by the same cause as : http://stackoverflow.com/q/5355805/1618363 

I hope that helps